# Ember.js: "Undefined is not a function" in internal bootstrapping process

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

The code below gives me this error in Chrome's JavaScript console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Stack trace:

```
(anonymous function) ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:22443
b.extend.each jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
b.fn.b.each jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3
Ember.Handlebars.bootstrap ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:22432
bootstrap ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:22454
(anonymous function) ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:12646
Ember.runLoadHooks ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:12645
Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend._initialize ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:26808
(anonymous function) ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:4504
Ember.handleErrors ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:411
invoke ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:4502
iter ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:4572
RunLoop.flush ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:4626
RunLoop.end ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:4531
tryable ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:4732
Ember.tryFinally ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:1199
Ember.run.end ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js:4735
autorun
```

Using Ember's dev version, this error occurs in the bootstrapping process:

```js
Ember.Handlebars.bootstrap = function(ctx) {
  var selectors = 'script[type="text/x-handlebars"], script[type="text/x-raw-handlebars"]';

  Ember.$(selectors, ctx)
    .each(function() {
    // Get a reference to the script tag
    var script = Ember.$(this);

    var compile = (script.attr('type') === 'text/x-raw-handlebars') ?
                  Ember.$.proxy(Handlebars.compile, Handlebars) :
                  Ember.$.proxy(Ember.Handlebars.compile, Ember.Handlebars),
      // Get the name of the script, used by Ember.View's templateName property.
      // First look for data-template-name attribute, then fall back to its
      // id if no name is found.
      templateName = script.attr('data-template-name') || script.attr('id') || 'application',

      /**** ERROR HERE ****/
      template = compile(script.html());
```

My HTML code (the JS is the sample code taken from Ember's homepage):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="mapTemplate">
            <canvas style="border: thick solid black" id="mapDesigner" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        </div>

        <script src="3rdParty/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="3rdParty/HandlebarsJS/handlebars.runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="3rdParty/EmberJS/ember-1.0.0-rc.3.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            {{outlet}}
        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
            <h1>People</h1>

            <ul>
            {{#each model}}
                <li>Hello, <b>{{fullName}}</b>!</li>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                App = Ember.Application.create();

                App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
                    firstName: null,
                    lastName: null,

                    fullName: function() {
                        return this.get('firstName') +
                                    " " + this.get('lastName');
                    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
                });

                App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
                    model: function() {
                        var people = [
                            App.Person.create({
                                firstName: "Tom",
                                lastName: "Dale"
                            }),
                            App.Person.create({
                                firstName: "Yehuda",
                                lastName: "Katz"
                            })
                        ];
                        return people;
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Library versions:**

Handlebars.js: 1.0.0-rc.3

Ember.js: 1.0.0-rc.3

jQuery: 1.9.1

**jsFiddle playground**

http://jsfiddle.net/t7qbe/1/

Comment: Look at the file/line number indication in the Error and tell us which line it is. In general: this error means that you're using a variable as a function (ie. calling it) but it has no value (undefined).

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I've already highlighted the "erroneous" line by a `ERROR HERE` comment, please take a look at the first code block. Looking at the stack trace, I can see that this error does not come from my code, it is started in Ember.

Comment: Look at the function on that line, one of them is bad. So either `compile` or `script.html` is not a function.

Comment: Pretty sure you want `{{#each controller}}` not `{{#each model}}`.

Comment: @MehulKar It does still not work. I thought `{{#each model}}` should iterate over each model and output its `fullName` property.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle or jsbin? Here's a [starter](http://jsfiddle.net/3bGN4/244/). Also noticed that you used `id` instead of `date-template-name` for your template. That might be a problem depending on which version of Ember you're using.

Comment: @MehulKar I'm using 1.0.0-rc.3. I've also added a jsFiddle link above.

Comment: @ComFreek, the versions of the libs you were using was off. I replaced them with rc3 of ember and handlebars from [here](http://builds.emberjs.com/) and now it works. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BTeMV/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The versions of ember and handlebars you were using was off maybe? Not sure what Handlebars runtime is. I replaced them with the correct versions from [builds.emberjs.com](http://builds.emberjs.com) and now it works.

Comment: I've just redownloaded the **normal** (not minified!) files from their websites and it works! It's probably an error resulting from the minification process.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem today while migrating an older ember app. The problem is caused by mixing templates of type `x-handlebars` and `x-raw-handlebars`.

If you compile your templates in production, then your build system is likely only bundling `handlebars.runtime.js` which is a subset of handlebars without the ability to compile templates. This is fine since your templates are already compiled to javascript.

However if you add some script `x-handlebars` tags to your html, Ember will as part of its bootstrapping process look to precompile those templates. But without the full handlebars library it will fail at the `compile` function.

Solution: If you need the ability to compile handlebars while still using compiled templates, ensure that your build system contains the complete handlebars library, and not just the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2014 -

Ran into same error when I switched to cloudflare.  This one was a real time suck to track down.  Wish there had been a better message.

Was using:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.1.2/handlebars.runtime.min.js"></script>
```

Swapped to:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.1.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

and error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the minification was the problem. The runtime version of Handlebars is intended to work only with precompiled templates. In this case, Ember will try to compile your inline templates anyway. More from the Handlebars site: http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html

[Here's a working version](http://jsfiddle.net/YcBEQ) of your JsFiddle, where I swapped out the `.runtime` Handlebars for the full version.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you sure that you posted the right jsFiddle link? It uses the same external resources as my fiddle. BTW please don't use `raw.github.com` URLs anymore because the latest Chrome will block those (MIME type mismatch). Remove the subdomain point and it will use a proxy tool: `rawgithub.com`, see [http://rawgithub.com/](http://rawgithub.com/).